# Gun is not connected to hand when imported to unity

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I made a shooting animation for my fps arms and gun, and it works great in blender. When exported to unity, the gun bone is no longer a child of the hand bone and the gun doesn't move with the hand. How do I fix this? I don't want to make it all one armature, because then I can't switch guns easily. I also don't want to duplicate the prefab to edit the gun and make it a child of the hand because then when I make changes to the gun in blender it won't apply anymore.  Does anyone have a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the parent/child relationship is established with a Blender constraint, that Unity doesn't recognize.

In this case you have to bake your animations: in pose mode go to pose menu > animation > bake action, and check the "clear constraints" option.